# Why is N necessary condition for S, if for S => N?

Tags: logic

I really have problem to understand the sentence.

Let's we have two phrases:
S = "Adam eats food"

N = "Adam is satisfied"

Let us consider S => N

Why is the statement N a "necessary condition" for S. I interpret this as: "Adam is satisfied" is a neccessary condion for "Adam is satisfied". The sentence: N is a necessary condition for S sounds to me like N can be only true, if S is true. What am i missing in the phrase "necessary condition"? This confuses me.

Comment: N is a necessary condition for S means that S can only be true if N is true, because N is necessary for S. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: S $\Rightarrow$ N doesn't mean that N can only be true if S is true, like Adam can be satisfied with other things beside food. But it is true that Adam is not satisfied, he must not have eaten food, so N is necessary for S to be true

Comment: It means that, in order that $S$ is True, **provided that** $S \to N$ is true, it necessary that also $N$ is true (because the conditional $T \to F$ is False). We can 
 read it also as: "it is not the case that we have $A$ without $N$".

Comment: Here, we need to understand the English word "necessary".  I wonder if the terms "necessary" and "sufficient" in logic were taken into English from Latin.

Comment: I think my problem is that i see the implication as S being timewise befor N. If N is necessary, it is timewise bebore S. Can anyone eloborate on that please.

Answer (score 1):

Let start first with this numeric example: $x^2+y^2\implies x=0$

$x=0$ is a necessary condition because if $x\neq 0$ then $x^2+y^2$ would not be $0$ (it would be strictly positive).

Transposing that to your example means that *"Adam is satisfied"* is necessary because would *"Adam be dissatisfied"* then he could not have eaten food (since eating food makes him satisfied).

So all comes from the contrapositive $\lnot N\implies \lnot S$, we must have $N$ verified in order for $S$ to stand, therefore $N$ is a necessary condition for $S$.

Answer (score 1):

"$N$ is *necessary* for $S$" means exactly that "the truth of $S$ *requires* the truth of $N$".

- In that case, it cannot be that $S$ is true while $N$ is false.
- Thus this is $\lnot(S\land \lnot N)$ , which is $S\to N$ .

"$S$ is *sufficient* for $N$" means exactly that "the truth of $N$ *is guaranteed by* the truth of $S$".

- In this case, it cannot be that $N$ is false while $S$ is true.
- Thus this is $\lnot(\lnot N\land S)$ , which is $S\to N$ .

---

So, $S\to N$ is "$N$ is necessary for $S$", and also is "$S$ is sufficient for $N$".